# Should I put money in both a ROTH and Traditional IRA?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, ira

I'm 31.  I put 11% of my $$ into a 401k.

I put about $600 a month into a high interest savings account.

I max out my ROTH IRA.

I'm wondering if I should max out a traditional IRA as well or if there is another asset I should be putting my money into.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your max contribution to your Roth IRA and your traditional IRA share the same cap, so if you are maxing your Roth IRA you cannot have a traditional one as well. I would put the additional into your 401k or perhaps a 529 if you have any kids.

Comment: You sure about that?  I think you can put $5000 in each.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. For reference:
Roth IRAs and traditional IRAs.
If contributions are made to both Roth IRAs and traditional IRAs established for your benefit, your contribution limit for Roth IRAs generally is the same as your limit would be if contributions were made only to Roth IRAs, but then reduced by all contributions for the year to all IRAs other than Roth IRAs. Employer contributions under a SEP or SIMPLE IRA plan do not affect this limit. 
From: http://www.irs.gov/publications/p590/ch02.html#en_US_publink1000230988

Comment: So just so I'm clear, I can't put $5000 into my ROTH and $5000 into a traditional in the same year.

Comment: Correct. You can have both, but they share that same cap. Contributing to one lowers how much you can contribute to the other. If you've already put $1000 in your traditional IRA, you can put, at most, $4000 in your Roth IRA that year.

Answer (score 6):

Roth and 401k are first because with the Roth you have tax free withdrawals (awesome!) and with the 401k you have tax free contributions (awesome!) as well as potential employer matching.  Traditional IRAs would be the final thing I would contribute to after both of those.  And in your case, unless you make around 150k, you aren't maxing your 401k; so I'd do that first.

Comment: $150K? Why would you think that? My employer allows 401(k) deposit up to 75% of gross pay, so $22K this year is enough to max out the 401(k) limit. Most don't go that high, 25% is common, needing $66K gross pay.

Comment: @joetaxpayer ah, good point. you could max it out at a much lower salary and a higher contribution.  I'm saying 150k because the asker said he puts 11% in the 401k.

Comment: Regarding the Roth allowing to withdraw  the money tax-free (once one's over 59.5-year-old): it might not be the case if you plan to live/retire outside the United States:  [Tax on money withdrawn from Roth 401(k) and Roth IRA when living outside the United States and over 59.5-year-old](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/86134/5656)

Answer (score 2):

Another option if it is available is a Roth 401k.  It is similar to a Roth IRA in that you pay taxes up front, but the withdrawals are tax free.

Comment: Are those only available through your employer?

Comment: Yes, and not all employers offer them.